# How to remove the first and last characters for selected text in Blender with script?

Tags: scripting

[image]How to remove the first and last characters for selected text in Blender with a script?

Comment: What text? Blender Has a lot of text everywhere.

Comment: for me it sounds a bit like a python, but not a Blender question...maybe elaborate a bit more what you mean? Which text do you mean?

Comment: The text object in Blender

Answer (score 1):

Text object's text is stored in `object.data.body` so it's quite easy with Python. Let's say you select all the text objects you want to do that to and want to run a script from the text editor:

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if o.type == 'FONT':
        o.data.body = o.data.body.replace("\"", "")
```

This removes " by replacing it with an empty string. You could also do exactly what you asked:

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if o.type == 'FONT':
        o.data.body = o.data.body[1:-1]
```

[See this for info on slicing (the "[1:-1]" part )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)
[And this for more about working with strings](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp)